# live tracking in laravel API using node js socket

Tags: node.js, laravel, live-tracking

How can Laravel API connect to a Node.js socket for live tracking? What are some suggestions for a live tracking in Laravel API?

Comment: In Laravel docs it explains: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/broadcasting

Comment: Or you can use socket.io and with js on client-side communicate with your node server.